# Jetty version used in latest geoserver 2.5.2 release

Tags: geoserver

What version of Jetty is used in the latest geoserver release (2.5.2) ? Is there a listing of library versions used by geoserver somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed GeoServer 2.5.2 version then look into C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.5\lib folder ( Check your installation path).

There you can notice jetty-{version}.jar file. in Geoserver 2.5.2 it is jetty-**6.1.8**.jar.

Also it's pretty easy to notice in browser if you use web admin tool. Just see in browser console F12, request details.
You will see in response headers:

```
Content-Length:0
Location:http://{server}/geoserver/web/
Server:Jetty(6.1.8)
```